# Is there a reaction involving alkene formation from diazomethane?

Tags: organic-chemistry

I need help regarding the following question:

[image]

I identified some of the compounds as follows:

[image] [image]

[image] [image]

[image] [image]

[image]

I think (G) should be Me₂C=CHMe because on reaction of (E) with HCl/Peroxide (Kharash effect doesn't apply) we form 2-bromo-3-chloro-2-methylbutane, which on reaction with Na/ether should be converted to Me₂C=CHMe (Wurtz reaction)...

I'm confused about the formation of (G) from (H).

Is there a way of preparing an alkene from another alkene by reacting it with diazomethane?

Or have I recognised (G) incorrectly?

Comment: Yeah, you got it wrong. Br atoms aren't next to each other.

Comment: Well, nobody would use peroxide if it didn't work. It's 1,3-dihalide and you make a cyclopropane ring, just like with diazomethane.

Comment: Is I formed from H instead of G?

Comment: @RobertDiGiovanni I too wondered the same but in the question I came across, G is formed from H and not I...

Comment: Your structure A is wrong. You won't get a alkene with molecular mass of 71 with that structure (on reaction with conc. H2SO4).

Comment: @RobertDiGiovanni May be you're right... As for the source of the question, I am not sure really!

Comment: @MathewMahindaratne Why not? Well in my opinion the alkene formed by acid catalysed dehydration would be (CH₃)₂C=C(D)CH₃... So molecular wt. = (9×1)+(2)+(5×12)=71.

Comment: Anyways thanks to all who tried helping!!

Comment: If you look at the structure, DOH leaves so MW is 70.

Comment: Your scheme is also not very clear. How did you get alkene H?

Comment: Well from what I have learnt, -OH would be protonated by the acid into -OH ₂⁺, would leave as H₂O, then rearrangement (D⁻ shift) would take place for charge stabilisation and then H⁺ would leave...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What I have finally figured out is that the problem here lies in the reaction of alkene (D) with N-Bromosuccinimide...
Here is how it should have been:

$$\ce{(CH_3)_2CH(D)CH=CH_2->[NBS] (CH_3)_2CH(Br)CH=CH_2 + (CH_3)_2C=CHCH_2Br}$$

Due to alkene stability, $\ce{(CH_3)_2C=CHCH_2Br}$ is the major product. Hence the rest of the products following (E) change:

(F): $\ce{(CH_3)_2CHCH(Br)CH_2Br}$

(I): $\ce{2-methylbut-2-ene}$

(G): $\ce{1,1-dimethylcyclopropane}$

Therefore (H) is $\ce{isobutene}$ and (J) is $\ce{2,4,4-trimethylpentene}$.

Answer (score 2):

For some reason, I thought this question is going to be closed eventually. The main reason is the title asking "Is there a reaction involving alkene formation from diazomethane?" but the post of the question says something else. And, then, OP has given his/her own answer, but that did not provide an answer to the question in the title. Thus, for benefit of education, I'd try to solve so many questions within OP's post. By the way, the answer to the question in the title is yes or no. Yes, only if ketene formation is counted as an alkene formation. Otherwise, it is definitely 'no.'

Let's see OP's posted question(s) step by step:

1. The compound $\bf{A}$ is optically active, which have a formula of $\ce{C_nH_{2n+1}DO}$. Since, the number of unsaturation within the molecule is zero, we can conclude that the molecule is an alcohol or an ether. The positive blue color test by Victor-Mayer test tell us it is a secondary alcohol. The positive iodoform test tells it has $\ce{CH3CHOH}$- function. Thus, the structure given for is partially correct. Why partially? Because OP has ignored the next step to produce dehydroxylated product $\bf{B}$, which have molar mass of $\pu{71 g mol-1}$. Thus, the deuterium ion in $\bf{A}$ can not leave the molecule fully or partially. The structure given in $\bf{A}$ would leave the molecule at least partially if it is subjected to dihydroxylation. Therefore best structure for $\bf{A}$ would have been:

[image: Structure of A]

When $\bf{A}$ is subjected to dihydroxylation, it'd give two alkene compounds (*cis* and *trans*), both of which have molar mass of $\pu{71 g mol-1}$. My version of the structure $\bf{A}$ should not undergo deuterium exchange under reaction conditions so that deuterium remains 100%. The next trick is when subjected to pyrolysis after esterification of $\bf{A}$, it didn't say the (major)product would be optically active. To me, there are two different $\beta$-protons, either of which can be eliminated during the pyrolysis as shown in the scheme (Ref.1 & 2):

[image: Structures of B,C,& D]

I assume, the "major" alkene must be optically active $\bf{D}$ because other path gave the product we received before in a different path. This optically active $\bf{D}$ would undergoes reaction to give an allyl bromide $\bf{E}$ as explain in the OP's answer. But unlike OP's structure, my product is chiral (although it gave a racemic mixture). All these and other structures are summarized in following scheme:

[image: Structures of final products]

Only thing missing here is the Wurtz product from the chiral $\bf{F}$, which I belive dimerized to give a six-membered product due to steric hindrance of bulky $\ce{Br}$ atom.

---

**References:**

1. Charles D. Hurd and Ford H. Blunck, "The Pyrolysis of Esters," *J. Am. Chem. Soc.* **1938**, *60(10)*, 2419–2425 (ODI: https://doi.org/10.1021/ja01277a035).
2. William J. Bailey and Robert Barkley, Jr., "Pyrolysis of Esters. V. Mechanism of 1,4-Elimination," *J. Org. Chem.* **1956**, *21(3)*, 328–331 (ODI: https://doi.org/10.1021/jo01109a017).

Comment: Thank you for taking time to explain! As for the title, that was what my question originally was... Still could you suggest to me what could have been a better title? I am new to the platform... 

Comment: Also there appears to be a problem with what you have described as (A)... It is supposed to form a salt (S) on haloform reaction, which converts into Me₂CDNH₂ on reaction with HN₃/H₂SO₄, which doesn't seem to be possible with your (A). Kindly correct me if I'm wrong...

Comment: I think it was a mistake.  The product should be Me2CDCONH2.

Comment: @MathewMahindaratne what software/tool did you use to make the diagrams on the  reactions and the arrows?

Comment: ChemDraw has done the magic.